# C# dividing an integer array using pointer

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, integer

So I have a quicksort algorithm, i have to divide my integer array in to two, and call both arrays back recursively.

```
partition(array,lower);
partition(&array[lower + 1], array.Length - lower - 1);
```

But c# won't accept that code, even though i tried adding unsafe, to partition class, so i wonder what must be done for that to work?

maybe i could fix it without using pointers, but i want to learn so every time i have a problem like that i wont have to change the whole code for it.

Comment: "c# won't accept that code"... does it say "I won't accept the code"? Perhaps instead, it says something more informative?

Comment: You don't need pointers and unsafe code. You can do the same by changing your method a little bit `partition(array,0,lower);` and `partition(array,lower + 1, array.Length - lower - 1);` Other alternatives like forming subarrays or Linq may hurt the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about linq?

```
array.Take(lower);
array.Skip(lower);
```

[You'll love it](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: It helps to forget pointers in c#, just copy data or make iterators; i.e. IEnumerable's

Comment: But it's like killing flies with cannons :P

Comment: Not really, firstly you are writing less code (always good). Secondly, you using the functionality of perfectly good iterator, why re-implement that? Thirdly, the iterator doesn't copy data, its a description how a data source should be traversed; so you've optimized on memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to create `SubArray` out of `Array`

```
    private static void Main()
    {

        int[] array = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
        int lower = 5;
        int[] array1 = array.SubArray(0, lower);
        int[] array2 = array.SubArray(lower, array.Length - lower);
    }

    public static T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] source, int sourceIndex, int length)
    {
        T[] result = new T[length];
        Array.Copy(source, sourceIndex, result, 0, length);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use unsafe code, you need 2 things:

1. Mark unsafe code with the [`unsafe` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (as you said you're doing)
2. Compile the project as unsafe by configuring the [appropriate setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)